# Is there something like a "symbolic link" (in *nixes terms) but for objects in ZODB in Plone?

Tags: python, symlink, plone, zope, zodb

Suppose I have an object in `/school1/document-rules`.

Suppose in another context, `/school2`, I need to have the same `document-rules` that is available in `/school1/document-rules`.

In ZODB, having `/school1/document-rules` and `/school2/document-rules` means I have two different objects.

I would like to know if it's possible to make `/school2/document-rules` **reference** `/school1/document-rules`.  So, `/school2/document-rules` would be something like a "ReferenceDocument", "ReferenceLink" or something like a symbolic link that would just point to `/school1/document-rules`.

Why? The document is the same, but sometimes it makes more sense (in semantic terms) to have the same document in different contexts. I have portlets that are rendered depending in their context, and I don't want to duplicate `document-rules`.

Does something like what I'm looking for exist? Bultin or using a module?

Comment: As long as the object being referenced is a proper `Persistent` instance, why don't you use the object itself directly? `Persistent` objects have their own identity. The DB won't copy them. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SimpleAlias](http://plone.org/products/simplealias/) does what you want. I've used it and it works well. You could also look at [collective.alias](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.alias)

Answer (score 1):

ZODB handles references transparently as you would expect in plain Python. You have a nice explanation [here](http://faassen.n--tree.net/blog/view/weblog/2008/06/20/0).

You should watch out for multiple references for the same object when you want to delete the object. For that you might want to use weak references for your 'symlinks' using the [weakref module from ZODB](http://svn.zope.org/ZODB/trunk/src/persistent/wref.py?rev=113734&view=markup) which is equivalent to weakref of the Python standard library.

Comment: So, I should create a content-type that implements a weakreference to another object?

Answer (score 1):

I've used a product called [RedirectionTool](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.RedirectionTool) for this.